# C - How is this function and pointer combination works?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I am trying to understand a code (below). I have even write comments on it to make sense of it.

```
// A structure with four elements (compound data type). Like class in OOP
struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
}; 

// A function to create above structure
struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    // Memory allocating. Returns pointer to allocated memory
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person)); 

    assert(who != NULL); // If false, calling process is terminated
                         // Check if malloc returned NULL memory

    // Initializing each field of struct Person.
    who -> name = strdup(name); // Like malloc. Copy and save the string
                               // Returns a pointer to it
    who -> age = age;
    who -> height = height;
    who -> weight = weight;

    return who;
}
```

So, let's say I want to create a person called Joe Alex. It would be like this:

`struct Person *joe = Person_create("Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);`

1. What I don't understand is the line

   ```
   struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
   ```

   of the function. The `struct Person` in that line implies the returned type data isn't? It is not the same as declaration right?
2. And why the function is a pointer?
3. And why when creating the variable `joe`, no pointer is needed for the `Person_create` function?
4. One last thing, why there is a pointer in the function(like below):

   ```
   struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
   ```

   I know it is for allocating the memory but why needs two of it (another one would be the function itself)?

Sorry if the question is confusing. I am trying to be as clear as I can.

Comment: The function returns a pointer to a struct. Look at it like this: `struct Person* Person_create(...` that is, the * belongs to the return type (a pointer), not to the function name.

Comment: You've got valid questions but they are also questions on basic concepts of the language. A good textbook will answer all of your questions.

Comment: Get a good C tutorial (like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming)), and work through it. You might want to get a copy of Kernighan and Ritchie's "The C programming language" and *do* all the exercises.

Comment: 4. What is "a pointer for a function with a pointer"? What is "a function with a pointer"?

Comment: What is "two pointers" you mention to in `struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));`? You mean `who` and one converted from function `malloc`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine.  To answer your questions:

1. This is the top of the *definition* of the function `Person_create`.  This function returns a pointer to an object of type `struct Person` -- that is, it returns type `struct Person *`.
2. The function *returns* a pointer.  Why it does this is, well, that's the way the program is set up.  It's possible for a function to return a whole structure (instead of a pointer to a structure), but it's usually the case that you want to dynamically allocate multiple instances of the structure and manipulate them via pointers, which is what this code is set up to do.
3. When you wrote `joe = Person_create(...)`, you were in fact returning a pointer from the `Person_create` function, and assigning it to the variable `joe`.  And you declared `joe` to be a pointer as well (again, of type `struct Person *`), so this is good, the types match, you're assigning a pointer to a pointer.  You're not *taking the contents* of the pointer (that is, you're not looking at what the pointer points to), so you don't need a `'*'` for that.  (More on this below.)
4. The line `struct Person *who = malloc(...)` is just about like the line `struct Person *joe = Person_create(...)`.  In one step,you are (a) declaring a variable having pointer type and (b) *initializing* it by calling a function that returns a pointer value.

The root of your confusion is probably that when you're working with pointers, C uses the `'*'` character in two different ways.

*In a declaration*, a `'*'` means you're declaring a pointer.  You always need the `'*'` to indicate you're declaring a pointer.  The declaration `int a` declares a variable of type int.  The declaration `int *ip` declares a variable of type pointer-to-int.

*In an expression*, a `'*'` indicates you're "taking the contents" of the pointer, or working with the thing the pointer points to.  If you're working with the pointer value itself, you don't use the `'*'`.  If I say `printf("%d\n", *ip)`, I'm printing the thing the pointer points to.  If I say `printf("%p\n", ip)`, I'm printing the pointer value itself.

Where this can get especially confusing is when you've got a pointer declaration with an initialization, because that ends up involving both a declaration and an expression.  Your line

```
struct Person *joe = Person_create("Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);
```

is fine.  But if you broke up the declaration and initialization, it would look like this:

```
struct Person *joe;
joe = Person_create("Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);
```

The second, assignment line would *not* look like this:

```
*joe = Person_create("Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);   /* WRONG */
```

If you can "wrap your head around" this last fact, if it makes sense to you that the `*` sort of disappears when you break the declaration-plus-initialization up into two lines, you will have really understood this.

Comment: I've understand! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

1. In `struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)`, the return type is `struct Person *`, not `struct Person`. C is free format language, and `int* hoge()`, `int *hoge()` and `int*hoge()` are all equivalent.
2. A function is not a pointer. Functions are automatically converted to pointer for `()` (call function) operator and other operators except for unary `&` (get address) and `sizeof`.
3. Creating variable has nothing to do with pointers for function. If you want to call `Person_create` function, the function requires a valid pointer because one argument is a pointet and the function use the pointer argument, so "no pointer is needed for the `Person_create` function" isn't true.
4. Sorry, I didn't understand your question. (See comment)